# How to find out used hash Algorithm

Tags: hash, sha256

I'm remaking .net 1.1 web into php. I have a huge database with users and their passwords, that are stored as hash.

In C# code I found this row

```
user.HashPassword = Globals.ComputeHash(user.Password, Globals.HashAlgoritm, null);
```

I looked in globals and there are

```
<add key="hashAlgoritm" value="SHA256"/>
```

But If I try to hash password in PHP with SHA256, results are different.

Example:

```
1) Password: emilekstrasa
2) C# password stored in DB: +3KhJwJelkTKk3J22dS03Aby7qKPV0WJYcd1tGhs71rTXjdVFQ==
3) Computed hash in PHP: 83672fe909062f7a28b2bdd8772bb88a42479fb0413e1ad50c83194a69316220
```

Isn't it posssible that 3) is only hexadec form of 2) ?

Thanks for advices.

Comment: I get the same thing in my terminal when converting `emilekstrasa` with sha256: `83672fe909062f7a28b2bdd8772bb88a42479fb0413e1ad50c83194a69316220`

Comment: The first hash seems to be base64 encoded, while the second hash is probably encoded with `bin2hex()`.

Comment: @martinstoeckli, I hashed the above example (#3) and then converted to base64 on the terminal, and it gave this output: `ODM2NzJmZTkwOTA2MmY3YTI4YjJiZGQ4NzcyYmI4OGE0MjQ3OWZiMDQxM2UxYWQ1MGM4MzE5NGE2OTMxNjIyMCAgLQo=`, so I don't think #2 is the base64 encoded sha256 hash of the password. In other words, `echo -n emilekstrasa | shasum -a 256 | base64` did not give the expected output...

Comment: Can you show the code for the method `Globals.ComputeHash`?

Comment: I cant find ComputeHash() function, The old VisualStudio has no ClickThrow. Give me a sec, I need to find it by myself. But thanks for advice.

Comment: Oh, I just found It, there is a salt appened to password. The function looks pretty difficult anyway. Thanks for your time guys.